# How MongoDb dynamic Child Object access in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

**How MongoDb dynamic Child Object access in PHP**

---

i have following example code, i need to do same query in php

i will show the SHELL Script to get the result in mongoDB

```
db.getCollection('Data').find({'COLLECTION.2017-06-16': {$type:'object'}});
```

How i can able to get result in PHP Collection Query with Array and Objects.

i have tried like this but its not working properly

```
$finder = $drum->find({'COLLECTION.2017-06-14': {$type:'object'}});
```

or

```
$finder = $drum->find(array('COLLECTION.2017-06-14' => array($type:'object')));
```

Thanks in advance i have attached sample json also.
please ref and give me solution.

---

```
 {
  "CODE": "XXXYYY",
  "COLLECTION": {
    "2017-06-16": {
      "TEST": "CLEAR"
    },
    "2017-06-17":{
        "TEST":"PUTPOST"
    }
  },
  "Success": true,
},{
  "CODE": "XXXYYYZZZZ",
  "COLLECTION": {
    "2017-06-16": {
      "TEST": "CLEAR"
    },
    "2017-06-17":{
        "TEST":"PUTPOST"
    }
  },
  "Success": true,
}
```

Comment: Quote `''` the things that need to be strings. `$finder = $drum->find(array('COLLECTION.2017-06-14' => array('$type' => 'object')));`

Comment: Its working fine now, Thank you @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. In PHP, you can't use the `:`, but need to use `=>` for key/value combinations.

Instead of `array(…)` you can use `[…]` for clarity.

You also need to enclose the array keys with `'…'`:

```
$drum->find( [ 'COLLECTION.2017-06-14' => [ '$type' => 'object' ] ] );
```

I would also like to point out that it is usually a bad idea to use a value (`2017-06-14`) as a key. It makes it often harder to query against, and even impossible to find a range of documents that fall for example in a specific month.

Comment: Hi Derick, can you please help me in other mongoDB issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896477/how-to-code-mongodb-foreach-query-in-php @Derick